# How to position a div inside of anoter div with values from textarea

Tags: jquery, css

I have the folowing script:

**HTML**

```
<div id="left">
  <div>Orange Div</div>
  <div>
   <div class="left_text">top</div>
   <div class="left_text">left</div>
    <textarea class="count2"> </textarea>
    <textarea  class="count1"> </textarea>
   <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   <button id="getText1">Move</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="red_div">
 <div id="green_div">
  <div id="orange_div">
   <h3>Orange Div</h3>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#left{
width: 150px; 
height: 80px; 
float:left;}

.left_text{
color: red;
height:20px; 
width:50px; 
float:left;}

textarea.count1, textarea.count2 {
color: red; 
height:20px; 
width:50px; 
float:left;}

#red_div{
margin: auto; 
width: 300px; 
height: 450px; 
float:left;
border: 1px solid ccc;
background-color: red;}

#green_div { 
width: 300px; 
height: 200px; 
float: left; 
display: block; 
position: relative; 
background-color: green;
border: 1px solid ccc;
margin-top: 100px;}

#orange_div { 
width: 100px; 
height: 100px; 
float: left; 
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Arial;
background-color: orange;}
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $( "#orange_div" ).resizable().draggable({
  containment: "#green_div",
   scroll: false,
    drag: function(event) {
        o = $(this).offset();
        p = $(this).position();
        $('.count1').html(p.left);
        $('.count2').html(p.top);
    }
});

function updateCoordinate(newCoordinate) {
    $(".count1").text(newCoordinate);
    $(".count2").text(newCoordinate);
}
    $("#getText1").click(function () {
    $("#orange_div").offset({ 
    top: $('.count2').text(), 
    left: $('.count1').text()
    });
});
```

**The demo is here:**

http://jsfiddle.net/emilsifu/zPHhp/4/

I need the orange div to positioned inside the green div, when the user enters values ​​in textarea from the left. The orange div is draggable.

Instead of that, it is positioned from the top left corner.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Seems to be putting negative position when entering in the text field. Wierd...doing some testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the html() and text() functions to the jQuery val() function combined with @jdpatel answer above seems to fix the issue. Because it's a text area, it seems safer to just read and write the value of the field.

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {

  $( "#orange_div" ).resizable().draggable({
  containment: "#green_div",
   scroll: false,
    drag: function(event) {
        o = $(this).offset();
        p = $(this).position();
        $('.count1').val(p.left);
        $('.count2').val(p.top);
    }
});

function updateCoordinate(newCoordinate) {
    $(".count1").val(newCoordinate);
    $(".count2").val(newCoordinate);
}
    $("#getText1").click(function () {
    $("#orange_div").offset({ 
    top: $('.count2').val(), 
    left: $('.count1').val()
    });
}); 

});
```

/*EDIT*/

When I tested it moments later it functioned differently again, and I can't seem to find out why. I have a found a way to make it consistently stay in the green box, never attaching itself to the body, but the left value entered only gets applied after the dragging has been done before. I can't find a CSS difference, class difference, ... It all works now, but only after dragging.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $( "#orange_div" ).resizable().draggable({
        containment: "#green_div",
        scroll: false,
        drag: function(event) {
            o = $(this).offset();
            p = $(this).position();
            $('.count1').val(p.left);
            $('.count2').val(p.top);
        }
    });

function updateCoordinate(newCoordinate) {
    $(".count1").val(newCoordinate);
    $(".count2").val(newCoordinate);
}
$("#getText1").click(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
    $("#orange_div").css({ 
        top : $('.count2').val() + "px",
        left : $('.count1').val() + "px"
    });
}); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add additional javascript given below

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js

and write functions in document ready like.. Its working..!

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {

  $( "#orange_div" ).resizable().draggable({
  containment: "#green_div",
   scroll: false,
    drag: function(event) {
        o = $(this).offset();
        p = $(this).position();
        $('.count1').html(p.left);
        $('.count2').html(p.top);
    }
});

function updateCoordinate(newCoordinate) {
    $(".count1").text(newCoordinate);
    $(".count2").text(newCoordinate);
}
    $("#getText1").click(function () {
    $("#orange_div").offset({ 
    top: $('.count2').text(), 
    left: $('.count1').text()
    });
}); 

});
```